# Conditionally deserialize an object based on JSON format

Tags: java, deserialization, jackson

I am using Jackson for JSON parsing and I have the following JSON structure:

```
["foo", {"baz": []}, {"myList": ["a", "b", "c"]}]
```

I would like to ONLY serialize objects with property "myList" into

```
public class MyClass {
  List<String> myList;
}
```

where `["a", "b", "c"]` is used as the value of `myList`. All other objects should just get turned into the default `Map<String, Object>` and everything else (arrays, strings, etc) should turn into whatever the defaults are.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the content [tree](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel) for the *"myList"* element and append its values to *"MyClass"* if it's to be found; otherwise, simply redirect the content to the standard deserializer.